# How to transfer control from one activity to fragment of another activity in android studio?

Tags: android

How to transfer control from one activity to fragment of another activity in android studio. For example I have activity A and B. Activity B had 2 fragments f1,f2. How to transfer control from A to f2?

Comment: What do you mean "control"?

Comment: Give some more explanation about your question

Answer (score 3):

pass some intent flag from first activity to second activity and in second activity use of getIntent() check the type of flag with the help of that flag open desired fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your Activity B in onCreate()

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new f2());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now,simply use explicit intent to go to Activity B from Activity A,

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```